# the library ArduinoJson has no member named parseObject for StaticJsonDocument?

Tags: arduino

I have just move to 6v from 5.8.0v of the library. And im get this error

'class ArduinoJson691_000::StaticJsonDocument<160u>' has no member named 
'parseObject'

is there a way that a can fix this?

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give us proper and verifable sample of your tryings.

Comment: ok sorry im new to this

Comment: is this better?

Comment: If you are programming your Arduino based on ArduinoJson library, you should read [Migrating from version 5 to 6](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/upgrade/) documentation regarding the changes on API. If you are using the ArduinoJson as part of dependencies, you should install the ArduinoJson 5.x until the dependency library that you are using migrated to 6.x.

Comment: thank you. I had not check will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this [arduinojson assistance](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/)
this will generate the code for you, for a given json object